# Eclipse: Auto-load html/JS changes during debug

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging, spark-java

I am running an app in Java Spark Framework.  I run it in Eclipse with `Debug-As->Java App`.  This successfully deploys the changes to the Java files.  That is, I save a Java file, and Eclipse compiles it, and the running app reflects the changes to the Java file.

Spark uses an embedded Jetty server under the hood, so this is just like running a embedded Jetty app in Eclipse.

Anyone aware of a good way to cause the HTML and JS changes to also be auto-deployed?

Answer (score 2):

In order to auto update the static files of your project, you can reference them as external static files. You're probably doing this:

```
staticFileLocation("relative-path-to-html-and-js");
```

Instead of the above, do the following for debug purposes:

```
externalStaticFileLocation("absolute-path-to-html-and-js");
```

By doing so, when you press F5 in your browser, you're going to get all your changes to html and js code shown. It's even unnecessary to restart de debugger. Restart the debugger just in case you modified your Java code.

Comment: Shoot, was hoping that would work.  I switched to `Spark.externalStaticFileLocation("C:/app/src/main/resources/public");` instead of `Spark.staticFileLocation("/public");`, but I still have to stop and start the server to get the changes. (BTW, cache is disabled in browser).

Comment: That's strange for me that you still have to stop and start the server. I'm working with Eclipse and it doesn't matter whether I press 'Run' or 'Debug' all the changes on my Web client (angularjs app) get shown. In fact, always when I work with Eclipse I press the Debug button, which allows hotfixes, and I can code even Java like if it was interpreted. It doesn't work like a charm, sometimes I get de 'undeclared method exception', but I do really restar the server a few times while working. Are you using SparkJava 2.3 with Java 8, or it's an earlier version ?