# SparkJava holding static files open?

Tags: spark-java

Now raised here:

https://github.com/perwendel/spark/issues/1001

(this thread now stale.  Please use the link above).

---

It appears that even after a stop() SparkJava holds static files open?

Background:

- Our UI developer would like to be able to make static file changes, save them and refresh the browser to see the changes.  This is a normal fast UI development cycle. To restart the app every time isn't acceptable in terms of development speed
- However - The UI Dev is receiving a "user mapped file section open" error when trying to save, indicating to me that SparkJava is holding the file open (!).
- So - we've tried implementing a "stop" so that SparkJava would shut down and restart when you pressed a key, expecting that this would release files.
- However - even after a stop, the files are still open and the UI designer isn't able to save them.  In short: with the exception of completely restarting the app we don't seem to have any easy way to achieve a typical UI development work cycle of "save, refresh browser" as files are being held open.

Frankly - we're creating a simple .NET app to to resolve the issue, as restarting and rebuilding the project every time when doing UI changes is far too slow.

Preferences:

- A switch within SparkJava that files are closed immediately after being read - slow, but provides for fast UI development cycles
- OR SparkJava properly releases all file handles on a stop()

Any thoughts would be appreciated, potentially we're happy to update Spark ourselves to achieve this.

Cheers - David

Comment: Try the following: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33703585/eclipse-auto-load-html-js-changes-during-debug/33722164#33722164

Comment: Given that the OP mentions .NET they are likely using Windows. I've had many file locking issues in Windows. Linux is a lot more flexible in that regard also they didn't show how they are loading exactly. If it is over a windows file share, the issue is further compounded.

Comment: This is a windows problem. Windows looks open files and will not allow any changes to the files while they are opened by a process. Unfortunately, since it is windows, windows sometimes fails of clearing this lock after the process has been terminated. As far as I can see, the only viable solution is to get rid of windows and run on an operating system that doesn't have this behaviour.

Comment: This isn't a Windows issue, but more the case that SparkJava must be keeping the files open after reading the content from disk.  - eg instead of try (Reader r=... etc) { read file, cache and return } it must be an open without a corresponding close.  I'm a little surprised that no SparkJava DEV folk have responded at this stage.  While I may try building Spark and sorting the issue out, this is squarely non-core for us and confusing that it is acting in this fashion, as the behaviour precludes Spark from being easily used in a DEV environment.

Comment: You can say it isn't a Windows issue, among almost all the other OSs in use today, it is the only one that handles files in such a way as to cause this issue. No user process has direct access to the file system, so it is literally Windows which is causing this issue. You can create a service to load the files into memory and add some functionality to reload and close the files, but as you mentioned this is DEV, PROD you cant control DEV use what ever is easiest.

Comment: Can you tell me how are you serving the static files ?